# Have to press Back button two times

Tags: java, android, android-intent, onbackpressed

I am trying to implement simple `back button` on `activity` to go to previous `activity`, but some weird behavior is happening when I am calling method `finish()` - the problem is I have to press `back` button TWO times? Why is this happening? In the back method i have only `finish()`. What is the other way to go to previous saved `activity` without `instantiate` a completely new `Intent`?

```
  public void back1 (View view){
    this.finish();
    }
```

This is second try with the same result:

```
 ImageButton buttonback = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton6);

    buttonback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            onBackPressed();
        }
    });
```

Comment: call `super.onBackPressed()` inside your `onBackPressed()` method.

Comment: how can button know to call onBackPressed instead of my back() function?

Comment: show your code please

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method onBackPressed(View) in the activity class com.bokaestate.krusty.drugi.ViewAd for onClick handler

Comment: You should post your activity code here

Comment: Code is huge. I just need hint as to why finish() restarts current activity, and on second click goes back..

Comment: Finish doesn't restart the current activity. Something else in your code is wrong but we won't know what because we can't guess your code.

Comment: you don't need to post whole code...just post the onclicklistener

Comment: Ok I posted, but everything is standard..

Comment: You are most likely starting the activity twice. When pressing `back` you are finishing one, and the other one is coming forward. Check your `onCreate` and `onResume` for anything that may be using intents or starting any activity

Comment: Activity are added in like in a stack the more u create and start an activity the more its added to the stack.As metioned by @bonatti check you activity starting code.Check if it is starting the activity twice

Comment: Oh yes. that was the problem.. I had both startActivityForResult(trecaAktivnost, 0); and  startActivity(trecaAktivnost);
Thank you guys!

Comment: Select an answer or edit/close your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are most likely starting the activity twice.

When pressing back you are finishing one, and the other one is coming forward. Check your onCreate and onResume for anything that may be using intents or starting any activity

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
```

add that to your code the super call closes the activity no need to call finish()

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the devices back button to function, **you dont need to override the onBackPressed method** in Activity.

If you want to place a custom button in view and set back action to that button, then you **need to write button clicklistener** to the same

```
    backbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            finish();
        }
});
```

Comment: Provide the entire activity code.. I assume you are doing something wrong.